# DRBD Too many messages after /sbin/drbdadm verify kernel: block drbdX: Out of sync:

Tags: high-availability, drbd

In all the systems that I am working with DRBD after verification that there are many messages in the log.

```
kernel: block drbd0: Out of sync: start=403446112, size=328 (sectors)
```

In some system might think it is by the workload, but there are some teams that are not nearly work.

The computers are connected in a network with 1Gb quality

These messages do not give me much fiablidad the system and that ultimately require cron to check the timing, and reset the fault blocks, which converts a synchronous system of course, in an asynchronous system.

Is this normal?
Any solution?
Any wrong?

```
common {
    protocol C;

handlers {
            pri-on-incon-degr "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-pri-on-incon-degr.sh; /usr/lib/drbd/notify-emergency-reboot.sh; echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; reboot -f";
    pri-lost-after-sb "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-pri-lost-after-sb.sh; /usr/lib/drbd/notify-emergency-reboot.sh; echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; reboot -f";
    local-io-error "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-io-error.sh; /usr/lib/drbd/notify-emergency-shutdown.sh; echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; halt -f"                                                                                                                     
}
    syncer {
            # rate after al-extents use-rle cpu-mask verify-alg csums-alg                                                                                                                               
    verify-alg sha1;
       rate 40M;
}
}


resource r0 {
  protocol C;
   startup {
     wfc-timeout  15;     # non-zero wfc-timeout can be dangerous (http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/3465-Is-it-safe-to-use-wfc-timeout-in-DRBD-configuration)
     degr-wfc-timeout 60;
 }
 net {
    cram-hmac-alg sha1;
    shared-secret "XXXXXXXXXX";
    after-sb-0pri discard-zero-changes;
    after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
    after-sb-2pri disconnect;
 }
 on pro01 {
   device /dev/drbd0;
   disk /dev/pve/vm-100-disk-1;
   address YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:7788;
    meta-disk internal;
 }
 on pro02 {
   device /dev/drbd0;
    disk   /dev/pve/vm-100-disk-1;
    address YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:7788;
    meta-disk internal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might happen from time to time and it's normal.
Just do disconnect and connect again - then out-of-sync blocks will be synced.

[DRBD - online verify](http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-use-online-verify.html)

Comment: Where is stated out-of-sync messages are normal? Is it in-flight IO that causes false positives in verify or something?

Answer (score 0):

There is a long story related to this (http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/drbd/users/25227) and still I'm not sure if this can be (or should be) fixed by DRBD developers or we need to fix upper layer behaviour (KVM in my case).